# How to apply gradient color in css?

Tags: background, css, gradient

I want to use gradient color as my page background 
how do I apply css to get gradient background?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See:

**[Cross-Browser CSS Gradient](https://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient)**

[image]
<sub>(source: [webdesignerwall.com](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/css-gradient-box.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[CSS 3 supports gradients](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) but this won't be supported by all browsers (eg IE6).

But you could do this, which I think is pretty similar to the previous answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    div#bg {
        background: url(http://www.khiba.com/PSP/FALL01/Testgrad.jpg) repeat-x;
        height:600px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your site to be compatible with all browsers, you can use this :

```
background-image: url(someurl.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

the someurl.gif image should contain the gradient that you want. Have it as a very small piece of image and you can extend it with repeat-x or repeat-y. whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the linear-gradient function in `CSS`.

Add this to your css file:

```css
    body {
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, COLOR1, COLOR2);
    }
```

Replace `COLOR1` with the first color and `COLOR2` with the second color.